# Generated JS Object into HTML not working

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to generate some HTML code with JS using a For Loop and an Object with a few different variables. I haven't done this with plain JS before, and I'm not sure how to do it. Can someone please explain it to me?

A few different things I've tried so far are 
`episodes[e(name)];, 
episodes[e.name];,
episodes.name[e];`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", theDOMHasLoaded, false);

var episodes = [{
  name: "Episode 1",
  date: "9/12/16",
  id: "episode1",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex voluptate repellat laborum dolores quisquam eos accusamus? Ipsa praesentium aspernatur numquam deleniti eveniet, consequatur laborum nesciunt vel aperiam. Fuga, maxime, magni."
}, {
  name: "Episode 2",
  date: "9/12/16",
  id: "episode2",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex voluptate repellat laborum dolores quisquam eos accusamus? Ipsa praesentium aspernatur numquam deleniti eveniet, consequatur laborum nesciunt vel aperiam. Fuga, maxime, magni."
}, {
  name: "Episode 3",
  date: "9/12/16",
  id: "episode3",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex voluptate repellat laborum dolores quisquam eos accusamus? Ipsa praesentium aspernatur numquam deleniti eveniet, consequatur laborum nesciunt vel aperiam. Fuga, maxime, magni."
}];

function createAudioPlayers() {
  for (e in episodes) {
    var playerString = "<div class=\"podcast-container\">"episodes[e(name)];"</div>";
    $("#audio-players").append(playerString);
  }
}

function theDOMHasLoaded(e) {
  createAudioPlayers();
}
```

```html
<div id="audio-players"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you making random guesses at syntax instead of learning the language basics first? Please demystify this for me.

Comment: ...oh yeah, now I remember why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

A few things jump out:

1. Don't use `for-in` to loop through arrays (without safeguards). That's not what it's for. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) *(also by me)* has a rundown of all your various options.
2. `episodes[e(name)]` is not how you access the `name` property on an object (and because of #1 above, `e` won't be an object, it'll be a string).
3. Putting identifiers next to the string doesn't do string concatenation (doesn't add their values to the string), and `;` are for terminating statements:

   ```
   var playerString = "<div class=\"podcast-container\">"episodes[e(name)];"</div>";
   // --------------------------------------------------^-----------------^
   ```

So for instance, here's how you might implement `createAudioPlayers` in ES5 and earlier:

```
function createAudioPlayers() {
  episodes.forEach(function(episode) {
    var playerString = "<div class=\"podcast-container\">" + episode.name + "</div>";
    $("#audio-players").append(playerString);
  });
}
```

Live Example:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", theDOMHasLoaded, false);

var episodes = [{
  name: "Episode 1",
  date: "9/12/16",
  id: "episode1",
  src: "http://traffic.libsyn.com/preview/securitybydesign/SecurityByDesignEpisode1.mp3",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex voluptate repellat laborum dolores quisquam eos accusamus? Ipsa praesentium aspernatur numquam deleniti eveniet, consequatur laborum nesciunt vel aperiam. Fuga, maxime, magni."
}, {
  name: "Episode 2",
  date: "9/12/16",
  id: "episode2",
  src: "http://traffic.libsyn.com/preview/securitybydesign/SecurityByDesignEpisode2.mp3",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex voluptate repellat laborum dolores quisquam eos accusamus? Ipsa praesentium aspernatur numquam deleniti eveniet, consequatur laborum nesciunt vel aperiam. Fuga, maxime, magni."
}, {
  name: "Episode 3",
  date: "9/12/16",
  id: "episode3",
  src: "http://traffic.libsyn.com/preview/securitybydesign/SecurityByDesignEpisode3.mp3",
  description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex voluptate repellat laborum dolores quisquam eos accusamus? Ipsa praesentium aspernatur numquam deleniti eveniet, consequatur laborum nesciunt vel aperiam. Fuga, maxime, magni."
}];

function createAudioPlayers() {
  episodes.forEach(function(episode) {
    var playerString = "<div class=\"podcast-container\">" + episode.name + "</div>";
    $("#audio-players").append(playerString);
  });
}

function theDOMHasLoaded(e) {
  createAudioPlayers();
}
```

```html
<div id="audio-players"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you like, you can also combine all of your `div` strings and then use a single `append` call by using `Array#map` then `Array#join`:

```
function createAudioPlayers() {
  $("#audio-players").append(episodes.map(function(episode) {
    return "<div class=\"podcast-container\">" + episode.name + "</div>";
  }).join(""));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

All you need is e.name (since you're already have e as each episode object), and make sure to change your quotes to be different (single quotes within your markup),
so it'll end up being

```
function createAudioPlayers() {
  for (e in episodes) {
    var playerString = "<div class=\'podcast-container\'>" + e.name+ "</div>";
    $("#audio-players").append(playerString);
  }
}
```

Comment: `e` in that code will be a string, with no `name` property.